# Fixing route and iptables for an OpenVPN tun0 interface, with a selected and safe routing

Tags: iptables, openvpn, route, openwrt, http-proxy

I did setup my router to use 3rd party VPNs for maximum security.
Since the ISPs that I am using have blocked all known VPN protocols including OpenVPN protocols, therefore I am forced to configure my router to use http proxy by that the OpenVPN can hides its fingerprint from the censoring ISP firewall.

That said I do use a third-party commercial VPN and use their OpenVPN tcp config file(s)
in order to make the unrestricted internet available to my connected devices.

Since the OpenVPN client needs http-proxy to connect to its server therefore I first setup the http-proxy on my router and then connect the OpenVPN client to the internet.

Please note that both the http-proxy and the OpenVPN client run on a **same** OpenWRT router, *no* separate devices!

That said since many of the commercial VPN providers on their OpenVPN server sides push their route and gateway settings on their client after the client establishes the connection, therefore the whole client lan interfaces including the router processor are forced to use the client redirected internet traffic and as a result the proxy process running on the router which should get its internet directly from the wan is forced to use tun0 interface internet and after few seconds it fails and as a conseuqnce the openvpn client fails too little later.

In order to prevent aforementioned issue I have added *no-pull* command into the *client.ovpn* file.

Please note that since I am using commercial VPNs **I do not have access to their OpenVPN servers**!
and my router does use *iptables(fw3)* and not the nftables(fw4)
so the client.ovpn file looks as follows,

`
client
dev tun0
proto tcp
remote XX.YY.ZZ.RR 443
nobind
auth-user-pass cred.txt

```
persist-tun
......
http-proxy 192.168.55.1 1080 auto
http-proxy-retry
route-nopull
```

`

The above configuration connects to the OpenVPN server (commercial server) like a charm and creates a tun0 interface on my OpenWRT router device.

I can traceroute a website via tun0 device with no issues,

```
#traceroute -i tun0 www.yahoo.com
traceroute to www.yahoo.com (87.248.119.251), 30 hops max, 46 byte packets
 1  *  10.124.148.1 (10.124.148.1)  1357.499 ms  195.523 ms
 2  vlan112.as02.stk1.se.m247.ro (146.70.16.241)  199.262 ms  190.672 ms  *
```

That said since I do not pull any route and firewall settings from the OpenVPN server so I should
make my own route and iptables rules as soon as this tun0 interface is created.

But before explaining more I should mention that my router local ip address is 192.168.55.1 and the br-lan (lan bridge) devices are getting their ip address from a DHCP pool address 192.168.55.65-192.168.55.126 or better to say (255.255.255.192/26) range.

My intention and goal is to setup the router to do following,

[a] all the devices on the br-lan (range 192.168.55.65-192.168.55.126) *except the router itself 192.168.55.1* should get all
of its internet traffic including ssh,dns,icmp,tcp,udp... from the tun0 device.

[b] For security reasons if there is no tun0 interface or no response from tun0 interface, all the internet traffic of the br-lan devices (range 192.168.55.65-192.168.55.126) devices except the router should get blocked from the internet, which it translates to all those mentioned devices should only and only get access to the internet if tun0 is up and responding, **no other alternatives such as weighted routes elternative paths** are accepted.

[c] All the br-lan devices *including* the router, printers, PCs, NAS, .. should be able to find, communicate with each other on the same subnet, with no restrictions.

I know there are some OpenVPN command that I can insert into the client.ovpn config file in order to make some routes possible such as,

*pull-filter ignore "redirect-gateway"* or *route 192.168.55.64 255.255.255.192*
but above commands has locked me up a couple of times and I could not access the router webpage,
in addition none of them worked as expected.

Furthermore, I manually executed following script after tun0 creation, but it did not let the internet traffic passthrough the tun0 on br-lan devices.

I created the ovpn table in the following file

```
/etc/iproute2/rt_tables
#reserved values
#
128     prelocal
255     local
254     main
253     default
0       unspec
#
# local
#
#1      inr.ruhep
1       ovpn
```

and

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -A FORWARD -i br-lan -o tun0 -s 192.168.55.64/26 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o br-lan -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

ip route add default dev tun0 table ovpn
ip route add 192.168.55.64/26 dev br-lan table ovpn

ip rule add from 192.168.55.64/26 table ovpn
```

I have googled a lot to find a solution, but I am pretty sure I should treat tun0 as a simple semi wan interface.

Here is my simple route table with no extra manual routing,

```
#route -n  
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.8.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 phy1-sta0
10.124.148.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 phy1-sta0
192.168.55.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br-lan
```

and more

```
#ip route show
default via 192.168.8.1 dev phy1-sta0 proto static src 192.168.8.118
10.124.148.0/23 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.124.148.113
192.168.8.0/24 dev phy1-sta0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.8.118
192.168.55.0/24 dev br-lan proto kernel scope link src 192.168.55.1
```

I would appreciate any hint or solution for mentioned goal, I am noob with routing and iptables.

By the way I do not know how to make the required configurations such as **if_tun0_up.sh** and **if_tun0_down.sh** automated to create and clear the routes automatically in the client.ovpn file.

Being able to make a **range of LAN devices** (br-lan) *except the router* to have their internet traffic from VPN provider.

*Securing and blocking* the LAN users from accessing restricted *unsecure* internet.
**Automating** the task of creating and deleting the *routes and iptables rules* with
**opening** and **closing** the tun0 interface.

Comment: Instead a setting up a vpn on your router, are you able to try on (virtual) linux VM. I personally don't have any issues with any vpn provider (proton, nordvpn) getting blocked

Comment: Owh yeah Do you want to route all traffic over the vpn or only certain traffic?

Comment: @Turdie 
Yes, in free countries you could use VPNs with no restrictions, by for my case the government is blocking majority of the VPN protocols such as OpenVPN, Wireguard,...

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but might get you in the direction. In the client.ovpn i would specify which network you want to go over the vpn, with the following statement in the client.ovpn. Fore example:

`route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 vpn_gateway`

Since you are using a commercial provider, the tun0 devices gets an ip address from their pool, so I wouldn't recommend making lan devices reachable. Most of the times it's a firewalled ip, with no ports open for the services you want. It's a client vpn. If you want to make your lan reachable over a vpn, you need a site to site vpn with your own vpn server.

Comment: The issue is that both client VPN and the http-proxy are running on a small router, no VM is available on this router but very limited linux machine.
What I need is correct IPTABLES, route commands with tun0 interface up and down.

Comment: In my experience when you use a vpn to a commercial provider, you get an ip in their network block. That ip is assigned to your tun0 interface. And when you use the tun0 interface to listen for specific services like DNS, that is not allowed by the VPN provider, so if you try to reach a a service which is going through the tun0 interface, you will never be able to reach that service. Probably also because a VPN provider doesn't allow incoming traffic to their VPN's

Comment: Ok, Just let me make this question simpler.

Comment: Ok, Just let me make this question simpler my internet Interface is phy1-sta0 with wg 192.168.8.1 as gw and the router ip address is 192.168.55.1 (on br-lan), the VPN tun0 assigned address is 10.124.148.113, I want all the pushed routes from the commercial VPN providers except following pushes,

net_route_v4_add: 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.124.148.1 dev [NULL] table 0 metric -1
net_route_v4_add: 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.124.148.1 dev [NULL] table 0 metric -1

That said I want the OpenVPN traffic be available for all the br-lan devices EXCEPT the router 192.168.55.1

Comment: I don't know this seems impossible to me it's either push or no push. With a commercial consumer vpn you have limited options to tweak/modify the config. As i said before the level customization you want goes far beyond a commercial vpn, you will need an enterprise vpn. There you specify on the server side your routes that's impossible with commercial home user vpn

Comment: Ok, let me refine the requirements and explain other possible solution.
OpenWRT router device has a http proxy server process that should run in advance prior to OpenVPN client start, the purpose of the proxy server on the router is to obfuscate the tcp traffic so the OpenVPN traffic does not get dropped by the govt. DPI.
I should assure one thing after the OVPN client on the same router gets connected to a commercial server, in fact I should assure that the proxy server process running on my router do not see any changes with its internet gateway or source.
How can I acheive this?